# LeetCode #37: Sudoku as Exact Cover Problem solved using Dancing Links

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, linked-list, sudoku, backtracking

### Introduction

I provide a regular `9`x`9` [Sudoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) solver, reducing the puzzle to an [Exact Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). The algorithm used is [Knuth's Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) as implemented using [Dancing Links (DLX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links). As I found no such solving technique on Code Review written in C#, I took up the challenge to have a go at it.

<sup>The problem definitions and used algorithms are behind links because it takes a lot of reading to understand these concepts.</sup>

---

### Challenge Description

This is a LeetCode challenge: [#37 - Sudoku Solver](https://leetcode.com/problems/sudoku-solver/description/).

> Write a program to solve a Sudoku puzzle by filling the empty cells.
>
> A sudoku solution must satisfy all of the following rules:
>
> - Each of the digits `1-9` must occur exactly once in each row.
> - Each of the digits `1-9` must occur exactly once in each column.
> - Each of the the digits `1-9` must occur exactly once in each of the 9 3x3 sub-boxes of the grid.
> - Empty cells are indicated by the character '`.`'.

---

### Goal

I'll first show the unit test that solves a board, before presenting a bottom-up presentation to come to this solution. Next steps include *exact cover* -> *dancing links* -> *sudoku solver*.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Solve()
{
    var board = new char[,] {
        {'5','3','.','.','7','.','.','.','.'},
        {'6','.','.','1','9','5','.','.','.'},
        {'.','9','8','.','.','.','.','6','.'},
        {'8','.','.','.','6','.','.','.','3'},
        {'4','.','.','8','.','3','.','.','1'},
        {'7','.','.','.','2','.','.','.','6'},
        {'.','6','.','.','.','.','2','8','.'},
        {'.','.','.','4','1','9','.','.','5'},
        {'.','.','.','.','8','.','.','7','9'}
    };

    var expected = new char[,] {
        {'5','3','4','6','7','8','9','1','2'},
        {'6','7','2','1','9','5','3','4','8'},
        {'1','9','8','3','4','2','5','6','7'},
        {'8','5','9','7','6','1','4','2','3'},
        {'4','2','6','8','5','3','7','9','1'},
        {'7','1','3','9','2','4','8','5','6'},
        {'9','6','1','5','3','7','2','8','4'},
        {'2','8','7','4','1','9','6','3','5'},
        {'3','4','5','2','8','6','1','7','9'}
    };

    var sudoku = new Sudoku();
    sudoku.Solve(board);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, board);
}
```

---

### Exact Cover

An Exact Cover Problem is a specific type of Constaint Satisfaction Problem where all constraints have to be met, and no constraint can be met more than once. Each set is a collection of candidate constraints. Finding a solution requires to find combinations of sets that meet all the constraints.

I need some configurable options, since consumers may decide how many solutions should be probed for. For instance, if you need a unique solution, search for 2 solutions and if the solver found only one, you know it's the unique solution.

```
public class SolverOptions
{
    public int MaxRecursion { get; set; } = -1;
    public int MaxSolutions { get; set; } = -1;
    public bool IncludeCluesInSolution = false;

    public bool HasRecursionLevelExceeded(int recursionLevel)
    {
        return MaxRecursion > -1 && recursionLevel > MaxRecursion;
    }

    public bool HasSolutionsExceeded(IEnumerable<ISet<int>> solutions)
    {
        return MaxSolutions > -1 && solutions.Count() >= MaxSolutions;
    }
}
```

Any solver implementation must implement the interface. Given a problem and some options, one or more solutions are probed for. Each solution is a set containing the id's of the initial sets used to meet the requirements.

```
public interface ICSPSolver
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<ISet<int>> Solve(ExactCover problem, SolverOptions options);
}
```

The problem's state is stored.

```
public class ExactCover
{
    public ISet<int> Constraints { get; }
    public IDictionary<int, ISet<int>> Sets { get; }
    public ISet<int> Clues { get; }

    public ExactCover(ISet<int> constraints, IDictionary<int, ISet<int>> sets, ISet<int> clues)
    {
        Constraints = constraints;
        Sets = sets;
        Clues = clues;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<ISet<int>> Solve(ICSPSolver solver, SolverOptions options)
    {
        return solver.Solve(this, options);
    }
}
```

---

### Dancing Links

Dancing links implements a fast algorithm for solving an exact cover problem. It works on a *circular bi-directional doubly linked list*, which also happens to be a *sparse matrix*.

To accomplish such Toroidal Matrix structure, we require a node.

```
class DLXNode
{
    internal DLXNode header, row;
    internal DLXNode up, down, left, right;
    internal int constraint, set, rowCount;

    internal DLXNode() => up = down = left = right = header = row = this;

    internal bool IsLast => right == this;

    internal void AddLast(DLXNode node) => row.left.Append(node);

    internal void AddLastDown(DLXNode node) => header.up.AppendDown(node);

    internal void Append(DLXNode node)
    {
        right.left = node;
        node.right = right;
        node.left = this;
        right = node;
    }

    internal void AppendDown(DLXNode node)
    {
        down.up = node;
        node.down = down;
        node.up = this;
        down = node;
        header.rowCount++;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<DLXNode> Iterate(Func<DLXNode, DLXNode> direction)
    {
        var node = this;
        do
        {
            yield return node;
            node = direction(node); 

        } while (node != this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var isHeader = header == this;
        var isRow = row == this;
        var isRoot = isHeader && isRow;

        return isRoot ? "R" 
            : isHeader ? $"H{header.constraint}" 
            : isRow ? $"R{row.set}" 
            : $"C({header.constraint},{row.set})";
    }
}
```

And the implementation of the DLX solver.

```
public class DLX : ICSPSolver
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<ISet<int>> Solve(ExactCover problem, SolverOptions options)
    {
        var root = Parse(problem);
        var solutions = new List<ISet<int>>();
        var currentSolution = new Stack<int>();
        var recursionLevel = 0;

        Explore(root, solutions, currentSolution, problem.Clues, recursionLevel, options);

        return solutions.AsReadOnly();
    }

    internal bool CheckForSolution(
        DLXNode root,
        IList<ISet<int>> solutions,
        Stack<int> currentSolution,
        ISet<int> clues,
        int recursionLevel,
        SolverOptions options)
    {
        if (root.IsLast
                       || options.HasRecursionLevelExceeded(recursionLevel)
                       || options.HasSolutionsExceeded(solutions))
        {
            if (root.IsLast)
            {
                var solution = new HashSet<int>(currentSolution);
                if (options.IncludeCluesInSolution)
                {
                    foreach (var clue in clues)
                    {
                        solution.Add(clue);
                    }
                }
                solutions.Add(solution);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    internal DLXNode GetHeaderWithMinimumRowCount(DLXNode root)
    {
        DLXNode next = null;

        foreach (var header in root.Iterate(n => n.right).Skip(1))
        {
            if (next == null || header.rowCount < next.rowCount)
            {
                next = header;
            }
        }

        return next;
    }

    internal void Explore(
        DLXNode root, 
        IList<ISet<int>> solutions, 
        Stack<int> currentSolution,
        ISet<int> clues,
        int recursionLevel,
        SolverOptions options)
    {
        if (CheckForSolution(
            root, solutions, currentSolution, clues, recursionLevel, options))
        {
            return;
        }

        var header = GetHeaderWithMinimumRowCount(root);

        if (header.rowCount <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Cover(header);

        foreach (var row in header.Iterate(n => n.down).Skip(1))
        {
            currentSolution.Push(row.row.set);
            foreach (var rightNode in row.Iterate(n => n.right).Skip(1))
            {
                Cover(rightNode);
            }
            Explore(root, solutions, currentSolution, clues, recursionLevel + 1, options);
            foreach (var leftNode in row.Iterate(n => n.left).Skip(1))
            {
                Uncover(leftNode);
            }
            currentSolution.Pop();
        }

        Uncover(header);
    }

    internal void Cover(DLXNode node)
    {
        if (node.row == node) return;

        var header = node.header;
        header.right.left = header.left;
        header.left.right = header.right;

        foreach (var row in header.Iterate(n => n.down).Skip(1))
        {
            foreach (var rightNode in row.Iterate(n => n.right).Skip(1))
            {
                rightNode.up.down = rightNode.down;
                rightNode.down.up = rightNode.up;
                rightNode.header.rowCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    internal void Uncover(DLXNode node)
    {
        if (node.row == node) return;

        var header = node.header;

        foreach (var row in header.Iterate(n => n.up).Skip(1))
        {
            foreach (var leftNode in row.Iterate(n => n.left).Skip(1))
            {
                leftNode.up.down = leftNode;
                leftNode.down.up = leftNode;
                leftNode.header.rowCount++;
            }
        }

        header.right.left = header;
        header.left.right = header;
    }

    internal DLXNode Parse(ExactCover problem)
    {
        var root = new DLXNode();
        var headerLookup = new Dictionary<int, DLXNode>();
        var rowLookup = new Dictionary<int, DLXNode>();
        var givens = new HashSet<int>(problem.Clues
            .SelectMany(x => problem.Sets[x]).Distinct());

        foreach (var constraint in problem.Constraints.Where(x => !givens.Contains(x)))
        {
            var header = new DLXNode { constraint = constraint, row = root };
            headerLookup.Add(constraint, header);
            root.AddLast(header);
        }

        foreach (var set in problem.Sets.Where(x => !x.Value.Any(y => givens.Contains(y))))
        {
            var row = new DLXNode { set = set.Key, header = root };
            rowLookup.Add(set.Key, row);
            root.AddLastDown(row);

            foreach (var element in set.Value)
            {
                if (headerLookup.TryGetValue(element, out var header))
                {
                    var cell = new DLXNode { row = row, header = header };
                    row.AddLast(cell);
                    header.AddLastDown(cell);
                }
            }
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

These unit tests should give you an idea how the algorithm can be used for trivial problems.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void ManySolutions()
        {
            var problem = new ExactCover(
                new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
                new Dictionary<int, ISet<int>> {
                      { 0, new HashSet<int> { 1 } }
                    , { 1, new HashSet<int> { 2 } }
                    , { 2, new HashSet<int> { 3 } }
                    , { 3, new HashSet<int> { 2, 3 } }
                    , { 4, new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 } }
                },
                new HashSet<int>());

            var solutions = problem.Solve(
                new DLX(),
                new SolverOptions());

            var printed = Print(problem, solutions);

            AssertAreEqual(@"
Constraints: {1, 2, 3}
Set 0: {1}
Set 1: {2}
Set 2: {3}
Set 3: {2, 3}
Set 4: {1, 2}
Solutions: 3
Solution #1: {1}, {2}, {3}
Solution #2: {1}, {2, 3}
Solution #3: {3}, {1, 2}", printed);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ManySolutionsWithClues()
        {
            var problem = new ExactCover(
                new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
                new Dictionary<int, ISet<int>> {
                      { 0, new HashSet<int> { 1 } }
                    , { 1, new HashSet<int> { 2 } }
                    , { 2, new HashSet<int> { 3 } }
                    , { 3, new HashSet<int> { 2, 3 } }
                    , { 4, new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 } }
                },
                new HashSet<int> { 2 });

            var solutions = problem.Solve(
                new DLX(),
                new SolverOptions() { IncludeCluesInSolution = true });

            var printed = Print(problem, solutions);

            AssertAreEqual(@"
Constraints: {1, 2, 3}
Set 0: {1}
Set 1: {2}
Set 2: {3} [Clue]
Set 3: {2, 3}
Set 4: {1, 2}
Solutions: 2
Solution #1: {1}, {2}, {3}
Solution #2: {3}, {1, 2}", printed);
        }

 string Print(ExactCover problem, IReadOnlyCollection<ISet<int>> solutions)
        {
            var b = new StringBuilder();
            var i = 0;
            b.AppendLine($"Constraints: {Print(problem.Constraints)}");
            foreach (var set in problem.Sets)
            {
                var isClue = problem.Clues.Contains(set.Key);
                if (isClue)
                {
                    b.AppendLine($"Set {set.Key}: {Print(set.Value)} [Clue]");
                }
                else
                {
                    b.AppendLine($"Set {set.Key}: {Print(set.Value)}");
                }
            }
            b.AppendLine($"Solutions: {solutions.Count}");
            foreach (var solution in solutions)
            {
                b.AppendLine($"Solution #{++i}: {string.Join(", ", solution.OrderBy(_ => _).Select(s => Print(problem.Sets[s])))}");
            }
            return b.ToString();
        }

        string Print<T>(IEnumerable<T> set) => !set.Any() ? "Empty" : $"{{{string.Join(", ", set.OrderBy(_ => _))}}}";

        static string Normalize(string input) => Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", string.Empty);

        static void AssertAreEqual(string excepted, string actual) => Assert.AreEqual(Normalize(excepted), Normalize(actual));
```

---

### Sudoku Solver

As a final step, we reduce a Sudoku board to a DLX matrix, solve it and map the data back to the Sudoku board. The format chosen corresponds to the challenge.

```
public class Sudoku
{
    public void Solve(char[,] board)
    {
        var problem = Reduce(board);

        // The challenge allows us to assert a single solution is available
        var solution = problem.Solve(
            new DLX(), new SolverOptions { MaxSolutions = 1 }).Single();

        Augment(board, solution);
    }

    internal void Augment(char[,] board, ISet<int> solution)
    {
        var n2 = board.Length;
        var n = (int)Math.Sqrt(n2);

        foreach (var match in solution)
        {
            var row = match / (n * n);
            var column = match / n % n;
            var number = match % n;
            var symbol = Encode(number);

            board[row, column] = symbol;
        }
    }

    internal ExactCover Reduce(char[,] board)
    {
        var n2 = board.Length;
        var n = (int)Math.Sqrt(n2);
        var m = (int)Math.Sqrt(n);

        // The constraints for any regular Sudoku puzzle are:
        //  - For each row, a number can appear only once.
        //  - For each column, a number can appear only once.
        //  - For each region(small square), a number can appear only once.
        //  - Each cell can only have one number.

        // For 9x9 Sudoku, the binary matrix will have 4 x 9² columns.

        var constraints = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 4 * n * n));

        // The sets for any regular Sudoku puzzle are all permutations of:
        //  - Each row, each column, each number

        // For 9x9 Sudoku, the binary matrix will have 9³ rows.

        var sets = new Dictionary<int, ISet<int>>();
        var clues = new HashSet<int>();

        foreach (var row in Enumerable.Range(0, n))
        {
            foreach (var column in Enumerable.Range(0, n))
            {
                var region = m * (row / m) + column / m;

                foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(0, n))
                {
                    sets.Add((row * n + column) * n + number, new HashSet<int>
                    {
                        // number in row
                        row * n + number,
                        // number in column
                        (n + column) * n + number,  
                        // number in region
                        (2 * n + region) * n + number,
                        // cell has number
                        (3 * n + row) * n + column
                    });
                }

                if (TryDecode(board[row, column], out var given))
                {
                    clues.Add((row * n + column) * n + given);
                }
            }
        }

        var problem = new ExactCover(constraints, sets, clues);

        return problem;
    }

    internal char Encode(int number) => (char)('1' + number);

    internal bool TryDecode(char symbol, out int number)
    {
        if (symbol == '.')
        {
            number = -1;
            return false;
        }

        number = symbol - '1';
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Questions

- Usability: can this code be reused for different variants of the puzzle?
- Usability: can this code be reused for different problems such as the *n queen problem*?
- Performance: can this algorithm be improved for performance
- General coding guidelines

Comment: [tag:programming-challenge] questions are on my blacklist so you'll get only a +1 from me :-]

Comment: Yes but this is a very interesting one. Try to ignore the challenge, and check out the algorithm instead ;-)

Comment: mhmm, still not sure. These _problems_ are of limited practical value if any. Though I have one thing: `new HashSet<int>(problem.Clues.SelectMany(x => problem.Sets[x]).Distinct())` Unless you're using some new hash-set, I'd say that `Distinct` is redundant here :-P

Comment: well, ok, I'll take a look... the linq queries I see here are hurting my eyes :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t lol, thanks for having a look. You are right about that Distinct, silly me :p

Comment: _These problems are of limited practical value if any_ -> not this one I reckon. Constraint satisfaction problem solvers are used for many problems, not just puzzles. They are very useful when generating schedules (railways, schools, ..)

Comment: So much `internal`... this is going to be hard work!

Comment: @VisualMelon perhaps it would be better to just have the class internal, and instance operations public... not sure, feel free to review me :p

Comment: No, it looks like a sane enough use (but yeah, making the class `internal` would probably be a good idea)... it's just that `internal` means 'this is tricky code I don't trust _you_ to use, but I still need it to couple my classes', and usually this signals lots of (probably necessary) complexity...

Comment: @VisualMelon That's a good point. using internal too much might lead to not caring at all about encapsulation within the assembly.

Comment: From what wiki says, is this algorithm just a nicer name for _brute-force_... right? _"the most obvious trial-and-error approach"_.

Comment: @t3chb0t It's not a brute force. It solves these puzzles on average 30 times faster as brute force.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a non-wiki page/article/document that would explain these concepts in a fashion understandable for humans? I sometimes wish there was no wiki because it spams all search results.

Comment: @t3chb0t At what insane hour are you awake mate? :o ... here's a link: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~jchu/publicportal/sudoku/0011047.pdf

Comment: I get up early every day and when the weekend comes... you can't help it, you're awake at the usual hour without an alarm o_O I like this pdf.

Comment: I actually was studing the algorithms for this question but then someone had to post the question about the builder pattern... you know how it ended :P

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah some things trigger something in you and you transform into .. r3ckEt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### SolverOptions

> ```
> public class SolverOptions
> {
>     public int MaxRecursion { get; set; } = -1;
>     public int MaxSolutions { get; set; } = -1;
> ```

Instead of using undocumented magic values, why not use `uint?`?

I'm not sure what `MaxRecursion` gains you. IMO it would be more useful to have a [progress report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) and a [way to cancel the search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken).

---

> ```
>     public bool IncludeCluesInSolution = false;
> ```

What's a "clue" in a general exact cover problem? I think this is at the wrong level of abstraction.

---

> ```
>     public bool HasSolutionsExceeded(IEnumerable<ISet<int>> solutions)
>     {
>         return MaxSolutions > -1 && solutions.Count() >= MaxSolutions;
>     }
> ```

Ugh. This either forces you to evaluate the solution set multiple times (if it's lazy) or it forces you to use a non-lazy `IEnumerable`, which means caching the full solution set in memory. IMO it would be far preferable for the searcher to return a lazy enumeration and simply keep count of the solutions returned and compare the count to `MaxSolutions`. Alternatively, and this is what I did with my Java implementation many years ago, the search could take a callback which accepts the solution and returns a `bool` indicating whether to continue searching.

---

#### ICSPSolver

> ```
> public interface ICSPSolver
> {
>     IReadOnlyCollection<ISet<int>> Solve(ExactCover problem, SolverOptions options);
> }
> ```

I'm not convinced by the name. There are constraint satisfaction problems which can't be reduced to exact cover.

See my comments above on preferring to return a lazy `IEnumerable`, which would mean changing the return type here.

---

#### ExactCover

> ```
> public class ExactCover
> {
>     public ISet<int> Constraints { get; }
>     public IDictionary<int, ISet<int>> Sets { get; }
>     public ISet<int> Clues { get; }
> ```

Why `int`? Knuth writes in a context in which everything is described in a fairly minimalist imperative language from the 1970s, but this code is in a modern polymorphic language. I would be strongly inclined to make the universe a type parameter, and then if the caller wants to number the elements of the universe and work with `int`s for speed of comparisons then let them, but don't make it obligatory.

For my taste the properties should all have read-only types. It is unfortunate that .Net doesn't have an `IReadOnlySet<T>`: I consider that it's worth writing one, and a read-only wrapper for `ISet<T>`.

I am baffled as to what the three properties represent. As far as I'm concerned the absolutely necessary component of an exact cover problem is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TUniverse>>` representing the subsets; and the other, optional, component is an `IEnumerable<TUniverse>` to detect the case where the union of the subsets is missing one or more elements.

---

> ```
>     public ExactCover(ISet<int> constraints, IDictionary<int, ISet<int>> sets, ISet<int> clues)
>     {
>         Constraints = constraints;
>         Sets = sets;
>         Clues = clues;
>     }
> ```

There's always a case to be made for copying your inputs to prevent the caller mutating them.

---

#### DLXNode

> ```
> class DLXNode
> {
>     internal DLXNode header, row;
>     internal DLXNode up, down, left, right;
> ```

See previous comments on using a modern language. I don't believe that it's necessary to manually implement the linked lists of Knuth's description, and by delegating that kind of thing to the library you can save yourself a lot of pain debugging.

---

#### DLX

> ```
> public class DLX : ICSPSolver
> {
>     public IReadOnlyCollection<ISet<int>> Solve(ExactCover problem, SolverOptions options)
>     {
>         var root = Parse(problem);
> ```

I'm intrigued by the name. To me, `Parse` means transforming a `string` into the thing it represents. What does it mean to you?

---

> ```
>     internal bool CheckForSolution(
>     internal DLXNode GetHeaderWithMinimumRowCount(DLXNode root)
>     internal void Explore(
>     internal void Cover(DLXNode node)
>     internal void Uncover(DLXNode node)
>     internal DLXNode Parse(ExactCover problem)
> ```

These could, and therefore should, all be `static`.

---

> ```
>                 var solution = new HashSet<int>(currentSolution);
>                 if (options.IncludeCluesInSolution)
>                 {
>                     foreach (var clue in clues)
>                     {
>                         solution.Add(clue);
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

`solution.UnionWith(clues)` would be more elegant.

---

> ```
>     internal DLXNode GetHeaderWithMinimumRowCount(DLXNode root)
>     {
>         DLXNode next = null;
>
>         foreach (var header in root.Iterate(n => n.right).Skip(1))
>         {
>             if (next == null || header.rowCount < next.rowCount)
>             {
>                 next = header;
>             }
>         }
>
>         return next;
>     }
> ```

Among the obviously useful things lacking from Linq is a function `public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> elts, Func<TSource, TValue> valuation) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>`. I heartily recommend that you factor this function out of `GetHeaderWithMinimumRowCount` and add it to your utility library.

---

> ```
>         foreach (var constraint in problem.Constraints.Where(x => !givens.Contains(x)))
> ```

`problem.Constraints.Except(givens)`.

Comment: Great review, I have a lot to refactor :) About that readonly set, .NET Core has a _ImmutableHashSet_ which I looked into, but couldn't use in my .NET Framework code. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1?view=netcore-2.2. The most interesting improvement to me is using the callback with caller code to steer the algorithm.

Comment: @dfhwze, ooh, I didn't know about that. Thanks. FWIW, you're wrong about not being able to use them in .Net Framework: if you follow the link text "*about immutable collections and how to install*" from the page you link, it takes you to a page which says that "*They're available starting with the .NET Framework 4.5 via NuGet.*" You have to enable prerelease packages and install `System.Collections.Immutable`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. _To me, Parse means transforming a string_ => I use Parse because in compilers, an input is 'parsed' into an abstract syntax tree, usually called ASTNode. To me, transforming the Sudoku input (whatever the input may be) to a DLXNode is the same concept.

Comment: _IEnumerable<TUniverse>_ -> this is _ISet<int> Constraints_; _IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TUniverse>>_ -> this is _IDictionary<int, ISet<int>> Sets_. I opted for a dict over enumerable of sets to let consumers of the API decide whether they want to map the matching sets (int, set<int>) using the key (int) or the set (set<int>). For Sudoku, I opted to use the key to map the results back to the board.

Comment: The whole point of Dancing Links is that it's a specific technique of implementing and using linked lists -- specifically, the name refers to the way one can "cheat" by not freeing deleted items from a list / modifying their pointers, so that they can be cheaply reinserted (these are the links that dance). If you're going to use generic linked lists from a library, it can hardly be called "Dancing Links" anymore.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, actually I prefer to implement it with hashsets. I do have some sympathy for your etymological argument, but IMO the key feature of algorithm X is the heuristic for deciding in which order to brute force. I see the linked list hacking as more a point of historical interest.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If talking about "Algorithm X" rather than "dancing links", sure. But Knuth's intention was to popularize the low-level technique of dancing links. (See the first page of [his 2000 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047.pdf) or TAOCP section 7.2.2.1 "Dancing Links" (out as Fasc 5 this week, [draft ps.gz online](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc5c.ps.gz).) He introduced Algorithm X (which otherwise has nothing much notable about it; it's pretty much the straightforward approach) only to illustrate it. DL is still more efficient so not only of historical interest IMO.